Flutter image picker: Camera crashes after appbundle deployment to Google Play Console
I'm working on a Flutter app that uses the image_picker package to allow users to select images from either the camera or gallery. Here’s the code I’m using:
Future<void> _pickImage() async {
    try {
      final String arg = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as String;
      final ImageSource imageSource = (arg.toLowerCase() == 'camera') ? ImageSource.camera : ImageSource.gallery;

      final ImagePicker imagePicker = ImagePicker();
      final XFile? imageFile = await imagePicker.pickImage(source: imageSource);

      if (imageFile == null) {
        Navigator.pop(context);
        Routines.showSnackBar(context, 'No image selected');
      } else {
        await _processImage(imageFile);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      Navigator.pop(context);
      Routines.showSnackBar(context, 'Error picking image');
    }
  }

 Future<void> _processImage(XFile imageFile) async {
    try {
      final MLKit mlKit = MLKit();
      final String extractedText = await mlKit.recognizeText(imageFile);
      _extractedData.clear();
      _extractedData = await mlKit.ner(extractedText);
      mlKit.dispose();
      if (_extractedData.isEmpty) {
        Navigator.pop(context);
        Routines.showSnackBar(context, 'No data found');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      Navigator.pop(context);
      Routines.showSnackBar(context, 'Error processing image');
    }
  }

The issue I’m facing is that the camera feature crashes when the app is downloaded from the Google Play Store, although it works perfectly when the app is installed directly on the device. This issue only affects the camera functionality, while picking images from the gallery works as expected.
Moreover, this issue does not occur on iOS; the image picker works smoothly for both the camera and gallery on iOS devices (enterprise build).
This crash is specific to the apps downloaded from Play Store only and is not reproducible in debug or release builds installed directly on the device. I’d appreciate any insights on why this might be happening and how to resolve it.
